# How can I keep two versions of the same package in archlinux?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I'm running Archlinux. Recently, one of the package named `icu` got updated; however, Firefox depends `libicuuc.so.56`, while R depends on `libicuuc.so.55`. How can I solve this problem?

Note: the R package was built against `Intel MKL` libiary, so it doesn't work on new version of dependencies. I tried to rebuild R -- it still depends on the old `libicuuc.so.55`

Comment: Such things should not happen with the official repo. Just if you haven't fully updated, as partial updates are not supported by the archlinux rolling release. If it is really like this (on a fully updated system) the you should file a bug.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assume you wish to run a specific executable with the old library. Let's call the executable `myprogram`.

If you place `libicuuc.so.55` in a different directory, for instance as `/opt/oldlibs/libicuuc.so.55` it is possible to instruct `myprogram` to use the old library with a command like this:

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oldlibs myprogram`

The library files can be extracted from the package file (that you can probably find in `/var/cache/pacman/pkg`).

If this does not solve the issue for how you intend to use the application, you can consider running it in a restricted environment (using `chroot`) or in a container instead.

Comment: Me having the mix of experience between *BSD and Linux I do think twice between calling it a jail or chroot. Is not the actual name jail, and chroot the command to achieve it? Otherwise, excellent answer sir.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that works. I should point out that I put `/opt/oldlibs/` into `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/R.conf`. (The `R.conf` file is already there, with `R`'s standard lib path in it. )

Answer (score 0):

my experience with arch linux

systemctl start mongodb give process start error

i simply hit  **journalctl -xe** to check current log

it show missing libboost_system.so.1.64.1 (old one)

it's a sumlink i resolve it using

```
readlink -f /lib/libboost_system.so.1.65.1  (new one)
```

readlink tell me symlink point to /usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.65.1

i extract boost-libs 1.64 from /var/cache/pacman/pkg and paste it's all /lib files to /usr/lib also **skip to override old file**

this resolve me breaking dependencies 
further work if not solve make a symlink of missing like

```
 ln -s /lib/libboost_system.so.1.64.1 /usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.64.1
```

**experience gain**

don't looking for patches 
always use  **pacman -Suy && pacman -S package_name** for install anything . partial update not supported  (in case of arch )